# Increase Ringer Volume on incoming call of certain contact. Android

Tags: android

Right now i have my contact picker returning the phonenumber of the contact. Im trying to match that number with the incoming call number so if it is equal it increases the volume to max. I can't quite get it. Any Help??

Here is my Code so Far. "number" is the returned number from my contact picker.

```
public class phoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){


            switch(state){
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                            break;
            }       

 }

 public class broadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            PhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener();

        telephony.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");


        if (phoneNr == number){

            amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

        }

    }
```

Comment: you can use the == operator to test for equality, unless it's a String in which case use incomingPhone.equals(contactPhone)  :)  Alternatively the "serious" answer is... "what have you tried so far, or would you like the whole solution from soup to nuts?" (hint: you're not likely to get that).

Comment: There i added my code of what i have so far.

Comment: did you log your numbers? I noticed that the incoming_number is shortened (e.g. no spaces) thus you may need to extend your comparison. For my app I simply removed everything but numbers and + before comparing

Answer (score 0):

In my comment I was being a smart ass and joking about how to compare strings, but looking at your code, it turns out it was salient advice.  I'm not sure what `number` is (I don't see it in your code sample) but since  `phoneNr` is a String, I'm assuming `number` is also.  In java you compare string equality not with `==` but with the String's `equals()` boolean method.  `==` compares memory spaces, so you'd be checking if they're both pointing at the same String object which they almost certainly aren't and even if they were you don't care.

Comment: I replaced  "if (phoneNr == number){" with " if (phoneNr.equals(number)){" and the app still didnt increase the ringer volume.

Comment: Your code should be moved into the switch. Where you simply "break" is where you should be doing the work of comparing the incoming number against the contact and all that... put some logging there to see for yourself if that code is, in fact, being called when the phone is ringing.  Also... very important... are you registering your receiver? If not make sure to look at the docs to do so, otherwise it will never get notified about anything. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I registered the receiver and now when ever anyone calls the app force closes.